# Spurious requests for a mailto page on server

Tags: php, mailto

I am trying to help with maintaining an old website.

I am getting spurious requests for /mailto URI addresses that were supposed to have opened a client side mail application instead. Here is some php data about three of today's requests:

```
[HTTP_USER_AGENT] => Opera/9.80 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) Presto/2.12.388 Version/12.10
[REQUEST_URI] => /mailto:info%40somedomain.com

[HTTP_USER_AGENT] => Opera/9.80 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) Presto/2.12.388 Version/12.10
[REQUEST_URI] => /mailto:info@somedomain.com

[HTTP_USER_AGENT] => Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.21) Gecko/20100312 Firefox/3.6
[REQUEST_URI] => /mailto:info@somedomain.com?subject=Helpme&body=Dear%20etc
```

Why do the browsers attempt to open these URIs on the server instead of opening the client-side e-mail application?

Here is some example html:

```
<a class="emailaddress" href="mailto:info@somedomain.com?subject=Helpme&body=Dear etc">Helpme</a>
```

Here is another variant:

```
<FORM ACTION="mailto:info@somedomain.com" METHOD="POST" ENCTYPE="text/plain">
   <table>
    <TR>
        <TD width="100">Name: </TD>
        <TD>
          <INPUT TYPE="text" NAME="name" SIZE="35">
        </TD>
    </TR>
    <TR>
        <TD>Your Message</TD>
        <TD>
          <TEXTAREA NAME="text" COLS="35" ROWS="4"></TEXTAREA>
        </TD>
    </TR>
   </table>

    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="7180">
   <INPUT TYPE="submit" VALUE="Send">
   <INPUT TYPE="reset" VALUE="Reset">
</FORM>
```

(Personally, I would not have implemented sending a contact form by opening the client side email client, and would also not have used a table in the form. I will suggest replacing those.)

Somehow some browsers seem to interpret this as though the user wants to open the page instead of opening the client email application.

What causes these incorrect requests to the server and what can I do about them?

Comment: Weird. The only reason I can see why this could happen is that the colon in the mailto links gets URL encoded at some point. Is what you show the final HTML? There is no post-processing of any sort?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out these interpretations were done by some malfunctioning spambots trying to submit links to their sites and other generic spam. So far, no real users tried to submit a form in this way.

Comment: +1. Yep, that's the answer I was going to give; it's pretty much only ever spam bots that do this.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](http://www.apptools.com/rants/mailto.php) the mailto action shouldn't be used, since it depends on software on the client. My guess is that someone has posted your form, but their browser doesn't understand the form action, and tries to parse it as html.

Comment: `mailto:` is a protocol (and even `whatever:` would be), if a browser wouldn't understand protocols at all, even `http:`-prefixed links wouldn't work. I think that's quite unlikely for a browser, unless it's a one that was just developed from scratch.